# NodeJS - How to wait until fs.WriteStream is closed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node.js-fs

I have some code that I need to wrap with mine, the original code is creating a `WriteStream` this way -

```
function createLog() {
    this.stream = this.fs.createWriteStream(this.logFilePath, {flags: 'a'});
    this.stream.write('log content');
    this.stream.close();
}

function testLog(){ 
    this.createLog();
    // Here I want to wait until the file is closed
    // something like this.stream.waitToBeClosed();
    let text = fs.readFileSync(this.logFilePath, 'utf-8');
    return text.match(
        `log content`
    );
}
```

then, in the end of the function the stream is closed using -

```
this.stream.close()
```

I need to use that function, and then examine the log file and verify it contain all the required data, but unfortunately sometimes the last lines are missing.
I believe it's because the stream is still not closed when I open the file for reading.

I know that I can use `stream.on('finish'...` to execute code when the stream is closed, but I am not supposed to touch the createLog code... (As I am writing a test for it) and before the execution of the createLog function I have no access to the `stream` object.

Is there a way that I can `wait` until the stream is closed from outside the original function?

Comment: Please show us the whole function that contains this code.  It's unclear from your description why you can just use the `finish` or `close` events.  Perhaps we need to see more context or know more about what you can and can't modify (and why).

Comment: Are you sure it is a close issue? Did you try a fsync? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandledatasync

Comment: @jfriend00 added code snippets to the post, is it more clear now ?

Answer (score -1):

If you really can't modify `createLog()` to provide the caller a means to know when it's done (which is really the right way to do things), then because the stream is in the instance data, you could modify `testLog()` like this:

```
async function testLog() {
    this.createLog();
    // wait for the stream to complete its work
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.stream.on('close', resolve).on('error', reject);
    });
    let text = fs.readFileSync(this.logFilePath, 'utf-8');
    return text.match('log content`);
}
```

Note, that `testLog()` is now `async` and thus will return a promise that resolves with the `text.match()` results.